# Terms and conditions apply meaning

Tags: expressions, legalese

I listen to an advertisement on Toronto News Talk radio, and often hear the expression

> Terms and conditions apply

at the end of the ad. It is spoken quickly.

What does it mean? In one 
[article](https://richardkennedysolicitors.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/%E2%80%9Cterms-and-conditions-apply%E2%80%9D/) I found that it is a legal term meaning in some cases (unfair deal) the law can change contract regulations.

Comment: The best interpretation is 'Ask your friends if they've had problems with this offer'.

Comment: That's the verbal equivalent of *[the fine print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_print?wprov=sfsi1)*, which generally makes one at least a little suspicious. Though if Canada is as litigious as America, it was prob lanky included as a sort of legal disclaimer (i.e. a CYA).

Comment: Yeah, it means ya gotta read the fine print.

Comment: No one in the universe has read the terms and conditions.  --[Eddie Izzard](https://youtu.be/N1ug9-rhSs4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a form of [disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclaimer), which allows them to make statements which may not actually be true from the listener's point of view.

For example:

> All widgets half price till Christmas.  Terms and conditions apply.

On investigation, the "terms and conditions" may include "Offer only applies to residents of Alaska", and so a listener in New York can't actually get a half-price widget at all.

This approach has been abused so much that in some places, the terms and conditions must be explicitly listed, and you will often hear this:  in this instance, the narrator would say "Offer only applies to residents of Alaska" in their fastest possible voice, at the end of the advert.

Advertising standards agencies might allow the use of a general disclaimer like "Terms and conditions apply" as long as the terms and conditions do not strongly affect the meaning of the advert - for example if it only applied to people over the age of 12, which doesn't really change the advert much for most listeners (on the assumption that an 11 year old isn't interested in spending their pocket money on a widget anyway).

Comment: It's worth noting that (at least in the UK) the phrase 'Terms and conditions apply' is usually immediately followed by the phrase 'See online for details/See in-store for details/Call for details/etc'

Comment: As well as possible geographical differences, the conditions involved are often bulk limiting (such as "no more the four items per customer/transaction"), pertain to other offers (a common one is "can not be used in conjunction with any other offer"), or clarify where the large print offer is ambiguous (for "buy one get one free" there is usually a statement with the other terms that "cheapest qualifying item is free").

Answer (score 5):

It means that the [terms and conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractual_term) as specified by the marketer apply. What those are depends on the marketer of the radio ad.

Therefore you have to investigate for each marketer what their terms and conditions contain. That however is not really a matter of English language but one of legal matters.

They speak faster to save air time which determines how much they have to pay the radio station.

Comment: Most radio adverts are required (by the radio station) to be 30 seconds long [citation required]. Hence speaking fast on the "fine details" isn't to limit how much they have to pay, it is to leave as much of the 30 seconds as possible for the actual advert.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "is a two edged sword since it is equally binding on the advertiser." (OP's link)

It is a *[cover-your-arse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass)*. They're covering theirs by telling you that yours is also covered to the extent permitted to both parties by applicable laws.

*Terms* are set by the company but the ultimate *conditions* under which they apply are set by law. For example:

> TERMS    &    CONDITIONS
>
> Residents    of    Alaska    and    Hawaii    are    excluded    from    and    are    not    eligible    for    this    offer.
> **Due    to    state    and    local    restrictions**,    ammunition    will    not    be    sent    directly    to    residents    of
> California,    Connecticut,    Illinois,    Massachusetts,    New    York,    and    Washington,    D.C.
> (collectively    “Restricted    Jurisdictions”).  –[smith-wesson.com](https://www.smith-wesson.com/wcsstore/SmWesson2/upload/popups/agreement/FunFunner-Promotions-Terms-Conditions.pdf)

This protects them from what would otherwise be false advertising.

*Conditions* also works both ways: "Some states do not allow limitations on how long an implied warranty lasts, **so this limitation may not apply to you**." ([xfxforce.com](http://xfxforce.com/en-us/support/xfx-warranty))

IANAL. I'm not sure if they're legally required to inform you of your rights, or if it's just a good idea to "C.Y.A."

---

More often than not, "T&C" are a way to underhandedly deliver a product's or service's shortcomings, to be in compliance with applicable laws. Which also makes it a great place to hide what they don't want you to know, *in the fine print*.

---

Here's another example of where a 'condition' may apply and why there's the age old saying, "May not be available in all areas."

> If your purchase does not come with a written warranty, it is still covered by implied warranties unless the product is marked "as is," or the seller otherwise indicates in writing that no warranty is given. Several states, including Kansas, Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Mississippi, Vermont, West Virginia, and the District of Columbia, do not permit "as is" sales. –[consumer.ftc.gov](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0252-warranties)

(*"as is"* is basically how you get around [Lemon Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_law) when you sell used cars)

If I were a used car salesmen, I wouldn't operate in any of those states and I would have a disclaimer (a term) stating that no deliveries would be made to those states. If I did do so however, the sale would be subject to the conditions (the laws) of the jurisdiction; my 'terms' notwithstanding. Thus the 'double-edged sword'.